# ASP .NET MVC 5 - URL Routing when using Sub Folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following directory structure where some controllers are inside a subdirectory:

```
 Controllers
     |
     |__Homecontroller.cs  
     |
     |__Accounts
     |  |
     |  |__PayableController.cs
     |
     |__Sales
        |
        |__ElectronicsController.cs
```

And I have the following structure for my views:

```
 Views
    |
    |__Accounts
    |  |
    |  |__Payable
    |     |
    |     |__Create.cshtml
    |     |__Detail.cshtml
    |     |__Edit.cshtml
    |     |__Index.cshtml
    |
    |__Home
    |  |
    |  |__Index.cshtml
    |
    |__Sales
       |
       |__Electronics
          |
          |__Create.cshtml
          |__Detail.cshtml
          |__Edit.cshtml
          |__Index.cshtml
```

How do I add a route so that when a user navigates to for e.g. `mysite/accounts/payable/create` the correct view is returned?

The following controller and routing doesn't work?

```
namespace MySite.Controllers.Accounts
{
  public class PayableController : Controller
  {
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            // DO some stuff

            return View(viewModel);
        }

  }
}

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Department",
            url: "{department}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "", action = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Use Areas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue, when I used same namespace for all controller, it worked for me.

In your case also try putting same namespace MySite.Controllers even though controller files are any sub-folders.